# Packets loss inside LAN for Windows 10 with Ubuntu sub-system

Tags: windows-10, networking, ping, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to reach win10 machine inside my LAN. It is accessible from other machines just fine. But I am having troubles with one specific machine. It has also OS Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18 subsystem. When I am pinging from windows cmd it has packets loss up to 25%-100%. When I ping same IP from Ubuntu it doesn't have any packets loss. Are there any network settings were affected when I installed sub-system? And how to trouble shoot and fix this issue? Disabling firewall on Windows didn't have any effect.
I tried to check firewall on Ubuntu with `ufw status` but got

```
ERROR: problem running iptables: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

[Pings from Windows and Ubuntu difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clJfh.png)

Would really appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried from my Windows 10 machine and WSL / Kali installed and the ping was normal. WSL should not affect the ping out. Try running TCP Reset and restart.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: @john thanks for the suggestion. I tried those steps and it didn't help. I blame it on sub-system or something related to it, because from it ping goes smoothly without any losses=)